# Why is this SQL returning two result sets?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, linq-to-sql

This test code is representing som code I have in my database, but when I use LinqToSql, it says the stored proc is returning two result sets....

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Test] 
    @a UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    @b UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    @c UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF @c IS NULL
    BEGIN
        SELECT        DISTINCT p1, p2
        FROM          dbo.Test
        WHERE         (a=@a) AND 
                      (b=@b) AND 
                      (c IS NULL)       
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT        DISTINCT p1, p2
        FROM          dbo.Test
        WHERE         (c=@c)
    END        
END
GO
```

I thought code like above would only return one result set? Can I force it to return one result set?

Comment: The code you have posted will only return a single result set.  Does this represent the code you have in your environment?

Answer (score 1):

Although better alternatives exist in newer versions of SQL Server, for reasons of backward compatibility many ORMs and connection libraries use the deprecated [`SET FMTONLY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-fmtonly-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) command to discover the shape of the result set returned by a Transact-SQL batch.

One of the side effects of `SET FMTONLY` is that it ignores all conditional logic and executes all logical branches. In your code, this will return two result sets. You can see this for yourself if you run:

```
SET FMTONLY ON;
EXEC  [dbo].[Test] NULL,NULL,NULL
SET FMTONLY OFF;
```

Based on what you are seeing, it looks like LinqToSQL is using this method.

You can sometimes get around this by adding:

```
IF 1=0
  SET FMTONLY OFF
```

as the first command in your stored procedure.

In your test proc this will clearly work; it might have undesriable side-effects in procedures that change data.